# Strange behavior with `weakref` in IPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, weak-references

While coding a cache class for one of my projects I wanted to try out the `weakref` package as its functionality seems to fit this purpose very well. The class is supposed to cache blocks of data from disk as readable and writable buffers for `ctypes.Structure`s. The blocks of data are supposed to be discarded when no structure is pointing to them, unless the buffer was modified due to some change to the structures.

To prevent dirty blocks from being garbage collected my idea was to set `block.some_attr_name = block` in the structures' `__setattr__`. Even when all structures are eventually garbage collected, the underlying `block` of data still has a reference count of at least 1 because `block.some_attr_name` references `block`.

I wanted to test this idea, so I opened up an IPython session and typed

```py
import weakref

class Test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.self = self

ref = weakref.ref(Test(), lambda r: print("Test was trashed"))
```

As expected, this didn't print `Test was trashed`. But when I went to type `del ref().self` to see whether the referent will be discarded, while typing, before hitting Enter, `Test was trashed` appeared. Oddly enough, even hitting the arrow keys or resizing the command line window after assigning `ref` will cause the referent to be trashed, even though the referent's reference count cannot drop to zero because it is referencing itself. This behavior persists even if I artificially increase the reference count by replacing `self.self = self` with `self.refs = [self for i in range(20)]`.

I couldn't reproduce this behavior in the standard `python.exe` interpreter (interactive session) which is why I assume this behavior to be tied to IPython (but I am not actually sure about this).

**Is this behavior expected with the devil hiding somewhere in the details of IPython's implementation or is this behavior a bug?**

---

**Edit 1:** It gets stranger. If in the IPython session I run

```py
import weakref

class Test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.self = self

test = Test()
ref = weakref.ref(test, lambda r: print("Aaaand it's gone...", flush = True))
del test
```

the referent is not trashed immediately. But if I hold down any key, "typing" out "aaaa..." (~200 a's), suddenly `Aaaand it's gone...` appears. And since I added `flush = True` I can rule out buffering for the late response. I definitely wouldn't expect IPython to be decreasing reference counts just because I was holding down a key. Maybe Python itself checks for circular references in some garbage collection cycles?

---

(tested with IPython 7.30.1 running Python 3.10.1 on Windows 10 x64)

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but `Ipython` saves results in the `Out` list.  Usually in interactive use that's not a big deal, but if you are tight on memory, or trying to add some additional reference counting, that could matter.

Comment: @hpaulj That was exactly my first thought. But since I do the initialization with `ref = weakref.ref(Test(), ...)`, IPython should only see `ref` and not the temporary `Test()`. Moreover, the message only pops up when interacting with IPython (after assigning `ref`). If I do absolutely nothing after assigning `ref`, the message won't pop up.

Answer (score 2):

In [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#reference-counts) on *Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter* under subsection 1.10 *Reference Counts* the second to last paragraph reads:

> While **Python** uses the traditional reference counting implementation, it **also offers a cycle detector that works to detect reference cycles.** This allows applications to not worry about creating direct or indirect circular references; these are the weakness of garbage collection implemented using only reference counting. Reference cycles consist of objects which contain (possibly indirect) references to themselves, so that each object in the cycle has a reference count which is non-zero. Typical reference counting implementations are not able to reclaim the memory belonging to any objects in a reference cycle, or referenced from the objects in the cycle, even though there are no further references to the cycle itself.

So I guess my idea of circular references to prevent garbage collection from eating my objects won't work out.

Comment: If you simply have the goal of preventing objects from being garbage-collected, just add them to a global "master" list that lasts for the duration of the program. Although I can't really imagine how this problem comes up - if you don't already have a reference to the object in a "natural" way, how can you also say that you need it to stay alive?

Comment: Regarding the difference between IPython and vanilla Python, I might have the details off, but, IPython's interface runs in the same Python runtime as the REPL, so when you make changes to the interface (like resizing the window), that executes code in the runtime, and every so often the garbage collector gets run, which deletes your object before you even put any more code into the REPL.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well, the module I am working on is supposed to read and write ext4 partitions. Reading some structure involves first reading a block of data from disk and then instantiating a structure from that block. But the structure will very likely have a short life-span. When it is GC'd the underlying block of data should be GC'd as well, unless it was modified. That's why I get blocks of data no object is pointing to. And adding the block to a master `set` on every `__setattr__` might (not tested) negatively affect the module's performance.

Comment: As long as there aren't cycles in your data structures "naturally" (i.e. besides the attempt to keep them alive), reference-count garbage collection is immediate, so there should be no concern about short lifespans.